# Liquibase/PostgreSQL: how to preserve table case correctly?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, case-sensitive, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase 3.1.1 to create tables in PostgreSQL 9.1. For example:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="bob">
    <createTable tableName="BATCHES">
        <!-- .. -- >
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

However, the table gets created with a lowercase name:

```
# select * from "BATCHES";
ERROR:  relation "BATCHES" does not exist
```

Is there any way to have Liquibase generate DDL that preserves the case of the table (and column etc) names that I specify in the change log?

Comment: How about just use lower-case everywhere?

Comment: Don't do it. Once you do that, you need to use quoted identifiers everywhere - something you don't really want.

Comment: @Mike - I'm also using H2, and I have DB instances for this app already with upper case table names.

Comment: I would change all your table names then.  You're going down a dangerous road here.  It'll just cause problems in the end.

Comment: If you *never* quote your objects you never need to worry about lower or upper case. Unquoted identifiers are case-insensitive. In H2 just as well as in Postgres (or Oracle, or HSQLDB, or DB2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS" attribute on your changeSet attribute or on the databaseChangeLog root element to override the default logic of "only quote objects that have to be"

Comment: This isn't applied to content of `createView`, is it?