# Liquibase - generate table names in lowercase

Tags: liquibase

I am using Liquibase 3.2.0 to perform an upgrade on an Oracle DB. All the existing table names in my schema are in lowercase

My problem is, when I use Liquibase to run a changeSet, the table names are generated in upper-case.

A typical entry in my changeSet looks as follows:

```
 <changeSet author="me (generated)" id="1403006263048-2">
        <createTable tableName="batch_job">
            <column name="id" type="number">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="batch_jobPK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="version" type="number">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="execution_time_stamp" type="timestamp">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="reference_region" type="varchar2(5)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="trigger_description" type="varchar2(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
 </changeSet>
```

However, the resulting table name is: **BATCH_JOB**

I have tried setting an attribute *objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS"* in the **databaseChangeLog** element, with no success.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I am familiar with the advice offered in [Liquibase/PostgreSQL: how to preserve table case correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616545/liquibase-postgresql-how-to-preserve-table-case-correctly)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in how Liquibase is handling case standardization. Could you log an issue at [liquibase.jira.com](http://liquibase.jira.com)?

For now, the easiset approach would be to use a `<modifySql>` block to fix the case of the table where it is a problem. Or just fall back on the `<sql>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nathan, lowercase issue is resolved by using `<modifysql>` as

```
<modifySql>
     <replace replace="filter" with="FILTER"/>
 </modifySql>
```