# Liquibase view name always in small case

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am creating a view using Liquibase. The changeSet is as follows:

```
<changeSet author="lalit" id="1">
    <createView  viewName="PS_Orders">view details</createView>
</changeSet>
```

It creates a view with name ps_orders and does not preserves the case. However the case is preserved when creating tables instead of views.

I have also tried this solution : [Liquibase/PostgreSQL: how to preserve table case correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616545/liquibase-postgresql-how-to-preserve-table-case-correctly) but that did not help.

My database is mysql.

Comment: Does it work when you are not using liquibase? (Just trying to identify if this is really done by liquibase.)

Comment: There is some  code that could be relevant here in [MySQLDatabase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/database/core/MySQLDatabase.java) `correctObjectName()`. It tries to identify the case sensitivity from the jdbc driver. But I would expect this to be equal for tables and views if this code part is really relevant. I might be wrong and that whole part is not touched. Anyways, try if it works without liquibase first.

Comment: @Jens You are right. The small case is generated without even using Liquibase. It was a different issue and I thought, it is because of case. Thanks for pointing.