# How do I set the Liquibase ObjectQuotingStrategy using the YAML format?

Tags: yaml, liquibase

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616545/liquibase-postgresql-how-to-preserve-table-case-correctly), the correct method of preserving case when creating database objects using Liquibase is to set the objectQuotingStrategy on the "root object", which makes sense using the XML format, but is less clear when using the YAML format.

Is there any way to set this property for the whole change log using the YAML format?

Comment: Case sensitive table and column names lead to pain and suffering in my experience.... Absolutely certain you need this? Using XML changesets might be the path of least resistance.

Comment: I completely agree on case sensitivity, sadly the database is legacy; the migrations are to be used for test dbs to validate against. As for XML, I would prefer not to use it and feel strongly that if YAML is a supported format, it should support *all* the features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just set it as a property of the root databaseChangeLog node:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - objectQuotingStrategy: QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS
    - changeSet:
        id: 1
        author: nvoxland
        changes:
```

However, it looks like there is a bug in 3.2.x that prevents it from being parsed at the databaseChangeLog level. I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1989 and fixed the bug in the 3.2.x branch.

For now, you'll have to set it on the changeSet level:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - changeSet:
        id: 1
        author: nvoxland
        objectQuotingStrategy: QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS
        changes:
            - createTable:
              .....
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is not valid YAML, even by correcting that error, it does not work.

Comment: On further research it does look like a bug in 3.2.2. I updated the answer and fixed the YAML.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the quick turnaround!