# Liquibase case insensitivity in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, maven-3, maven-plugin, liquibase

Based on this [Making case insensitive table with liquibase in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996020/making-case-insensitive-table-with-liquibase-in-postgres/26234578#26234578)

The postgresql creates tables

```
create table "Users" ("userId" integer unique not null, "userFirstName" varchar(50) not null,"userLastName" varchar(50) not null);
```

instead of

```
create table Users (userId integer unique not null, userFirstName varchar(50) not null,userLastName varchar(50) not null);
```

This causes issues with the jpa.

How can I force the liquibase maven plugin use this sub class in order to get the insensitivity with liquibase in postgres?

Comment: It would be _much_ better to convince JPA to *never* quote  identifiers.

Comment: The problem is that the jpa does not quote the identifiers, the liquibase plugin does for postgresql.

Comment: I guess the best option is to simply write everything in lowercase in your Liquibase changelog. That way Liquibase doesn't quote the names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name in the comments above:

> I guess the best option is to simply write everything in lowercase in your Liquibase changelog. That way Liquibase doesn't quote the names

Comment: Yeah, that's sorta the obvious solution, though it would be much better if the lowercasing was automatic.